# Can I connect 3 monitors to my Dell CPU using N210-MD1G/D3 card?

Tags: multiple-monitors

Please advise me on how I can connect 3 monitors to my dell computer using N210-MD1G/D3 graphics card.

I am currently experiencing difficulties in achieving this.

I am using Windows 7. It is a desktop DELL OPTIPLEX 3010. The monitors do not have DVI or HDMI ports
I have a DVI adaptor/cable, but the onboard VGA port is inactive after connecting one monitor on N210-MD1G/D3 card

Comment: What operating system? Is this a laptop or a desktop? I will guess a desktop based on the graphics card you mention. What have you tried? The card seems to have three ports, DVI,HDMI and VGA. Do you have three screens each with one of those connections?

Comment: i am using windows 7. its a desktop DELL OPTIPLEX 3010. the screens i have do not have DVI and HDMI ports.

Comment: i have a DVI adaptor/cable, but i notice the onboard VGA port inactive after connecting one screen on N210-MD1G/D3 card

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this extra information. You are getting down voted precisely because you did not mention this type of thing. Have a look through our [help](http://superuser.com/help) page to learn how to ask good questions. Mention the things you have tried, how and why they failed, the symptoms you get, the OS you are working on, anything that could be relevant. As it stands your question can be answered by "connect the screen's cables to your graphics card".

Answer (score 0):

With a grain of salt, but [this website](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=1118778) says only 2 monitors max are supported on that card, meaning you can use either two of the three interfaces at once.

Update: Based on your comments (you only have VGA monitors?) you'll need a [DVI to VGA adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000067SOH). Again, this will only give a maximum of two monitors on this card.

Answer (score 0):

I found the AMD HD 7750 Bizview works great in other models of Dells such as the 780 and 760.  It allows VGA connections but you must order an extra Mini Display port adapter to VGA for about $20.00 so both cost about $150.00 but give great Windows numbers in 7 32 or 64 bit.

Anothe plus is that you can put in slim cases since it comes with a low profile adapter plate.

Let me know if you need additional info.  Purchased all items from Newegg.